# SQL Server Date and Time Format using strings

Tags: sql-server, datetime, format

I was always under the impression given a `datetime` data type as `2019-07-06` was always 6th July 2019, regardless of locale and regional settings, ie this is a universal datetime format.

However, I've ran into a situation where I am trying to query some data from our database, and the string `2019-07-06` does not return the expected results.  However `2019-06-07` will.

I have always had the understanding that `YYYY-MM-DD` format was based on [ISO-8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601).

Given this was on Friday 7th June where I was inserting the data, and today I am querying that data, I see:

[image: query result]

Using the query

```
select 
      b.ID
    , b.UserId
    , b.EntryDate
    , day(b.EntryDate) as 'day'
    , month(b.EntryDate) as 'month'
from [dbo].[SomeTable] b
where b.UserId = 236328
```

But when I change the query:

```
select 
      b.ID
    , b.UserId
    , b.EntryDate
    , day(b.EntryDate) as 'day'
    , month(b.EntryDate) as 'month'
from [dbo].[SomeTable] b
where b.UserId = 236328
and b.EntryDate > '2019-06-07'
```

This does not yield any results.  However changing `EntryDate > '2019-07-06'` will return my data.

**NOTE:** The query is entered using SSMS v18 on my local machine.

### Server Configuration

The current verison of SQL Server is `Microsoft SQL Server 2012 (SP4-GDR) (KB4057116) - 11.0.7462.6 (X64)   Jan  5 2018 22:11:56   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Developer Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.3 <X64> (Build 9600: )`

The sql server is configured to use:

```
|------------------|------------------------------|
| Setting          | Value                        |
|------------------|------------------------------|
| Language         | English (United States)      |
| Default Language | British English              |
| Server Collation | SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS |
```

### Database Configuration

The database is configured to use:

```
|---------------------|-----------------------|
| Setting             | Value                 |
|---------------------|-----------------------|
| Collation           | Latin1_General_CI_AS  |
| Compatability Level | SQL Server 2012 (110) |
| Default Language    | British English       |
```

Question is, what should be the expected behaviour of date time queries with strings with format `YYYY-MM-dd`?  I cannot recall this behaviour I am seeing in the last 20 years.

**Update**

For the record, if I enter the datetime in the query as `2019-06-07T00:00:00` then this **DOES** return the expected data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the `DATETIME` type, the literal `2019-06-07` could be 7th June, or 6th July, depending on the current `DATEFORMAT` settings:

```
SET DATEFORMAT DMY;
SELECT FORMAT(CONVERT(DATETIME, '2019-06-07'), 'dd MMM yy');

--Returns "06 Jul 19"

SET DATEFORMAT MDY;
SELECT FORMAT(CONVERT(DATETIME, '2019-06-07'), 'dd MMM yy');

-- Returns "07 Jun 19"
```

You should not rely on your default server settings for this, the best way to avoid this ambiguity is to use the format `yyyyMMdd`, this is always interpreted the same way regardless of settings:

```
SET DATEFORMAT DMY;
SELECT FORMAT(CONVERT(DATETIME, '20190607'), 'dd MMM yy');

--Returns "07 Jun 19"

SET DATEFORMAT MDY;
SELECT FORMAT(CONVERT(DATETIME, '20190607'), 'dd MMM yy');

-- Returns "07 Jun 19"
```

Alternatively, do an explicit conversion, and use the style parameter to ensure consistent conversion:

```
SET DATEFORMAT DMY;
SELECT FORMAT(CONVERT(DATETIME, '2019-06-07', 101), 'dd MMM yy');

-- Returns "07 Jun 19"

SET DATEFORMAT MDY;
SELECT FORMAT(CONVERT(DATETIME, '2019-06-07', 101), 'dd MMM yy');

-- Returns "07 Jun 19"
```

As an aside there is no ambiguity with this format when working with `DATE` or `DATETIME2`, but this ambiguity has always existed for `DATETIME` and `SMALLDATETIME`. Aaron Bertrand blogged about this in his Bad habits to kick series: [mis-handling date / range queries](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mis-handling-date-range-queries)